# How to get PATH of WEB-INF in java file

Tags: java

What i am doing. I am going to read CSV file which is located inside WEB-INF folder and i reading that file in MyService.java file which is completely plain java file.

I used like

```
 maxChineseListing=1
 maxFixedListing=1
 #Change below mode to prod if we wish to update the ebay server
 testMode=true
 dataFolder= /WEB-INF/
 #Sleep time in minutes
 sleepTime=70

 File dataFolderFile = new File(dataFolder);
```

i used WEB-INF/,/WEB-INF/ too

Can anyone help me.How to do that how can we get CSV file path from WEB-INF.

Comment: I tried /WEB-INF/mycsv.csv but it is giving error like ExceptionInInitializerError.

Comment: If your application is driven by a Spring, you could use `ClassPathResource` I/O utility class. Back to Google and then come back with questions! Very badly composed question.

Comment: Neither you have mentioned your efforts nor you have mentioned what the problem is..Hence downvoting

Comment: If your application isn't a Servlet or something higher built on that technology, you don't *have* a WEB-INF directory. Or if you do, it has no useful purpose beyond any other directory in your application. Unclear what you're actually talking about here.

Comment: I have written Service for that so therefore i am telling this is plain java file.

Comment: So your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

```
ServletContext servletContext = getContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/filename.extension");
```

Comment: Hi i am on Plain Java file.Its not a servlet.

Comment: As your question mentioned its a web project `ServletContext` will available for you But here you can for solution https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/how-to-get-web-inf-path-outside-java-servlet/